# Please correct the PHP script

Tags: php

Error:  Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

```
<?php
$msg='';

$days=0;
if (isset($_POST['btnCreate']))
{
       $join = date_create($_POST['join']);

       $today = date_create(date('Y-m-d'));
       $diff=  date_diff($join,$today);
       $days=$diff->format("%a");
       $msg=$days.' days greater than today ';


}
?>
 <div style="text-align: center">
 <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
     <input type="date" name="join"  id="joinid" value="<?php echo $join;?>" class="txtbox"><br>
     <div class="error" id="joinerr"><?php echo $msg; ?></div><br/>
      <input type="submit" name="btnCreate" class="btns" value="Create Account">
 </form>
 </div>
```

Where is the error? Correct it Post the entire corrected code so that I can spot out the difference.

Comment: You should ask for solutions to solve a problem, not asking people to work for you.

Comment: I want to only know about solution for error of my code
 Please help

Answer (score 0):

Be plain, are you searching for error or trying to write a date string?

```
<?php
$dt = new DateTime();
echo $dt -> format('H:i:s');
?>
```